# Is Swift generics capable of limiting methods to expose with where clause?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

Using Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.

I'm extending some NSObject subclasses with a generic struct and a protocol extension.

**My Implementation**

```
struct MethodHolder<T: NSObject> {
    let object: T
}

extension MethodHolder where T: UIView {
    func view() {}
}

extension MethodHolder where T: UILabel {
    func label() {}
}

extension MethodHolder where T: UIButton {
    func button() {}
}

protocol MethodHolderProtocol {}
extension MethodHolderProtocol where Self: NSObject {
    var methodHolder: MethodHolder<Self> {
    return MethodHolder(object: self)
}
extension NSObject: MethodHolderProtocol {}
```

---

**Expected behavior:**

```
UIView().methodHolder
```

only has **view()** method.

```
UILabel().methodHolder
```

only has **view()** method and **label()**.

```
UIButton().methodHolder
```

only has **view()** method and **button()**.

---

**Actual behavior**

```
UIView().methodHolder
UILabel().methodHolder
UIButton().methodHolder
```

Those all have **view()**, **label()** and **button()** methods.

---

**Question**

How can I constrain those methods to expose in appropriate type? Is this approach to achieve that is wrong first of all?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Actually I think it is a bug of Xcode, because when you use `UIView().methodHolder.label()`, the compiler do yelling there is a error.

Comment: You should file a bug with Apple https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Ah, a bug... I haven't thought of that. Thanks for that. I will report the issue.

Comment: This appears to be working now. Tested on Swift 4, Xcode 9 Beta.